# Syntax of SQL in query for adding certain null fields to a table

Tags: vba, ms-access

Im trying to create a query that will add to an existing table (tblExceptions) the following:

- Fields Event Title, Event Date, Last Name, First Name & email - These fields must get added to the tblExceptions
- All other fields that are null for that record.

It should be noted however that a record can only be added if a field in the source table (tblData) is missing.

I created a rather large query in the design view for queries in MS Access that adds all for that record if it contains a missing piece of data but am reluctant to change the insert incase it doesn't add the null field.

Any ideas? I'm thinking that the INSERT INTO may need to contain an IF statement - does MS access allow this?

Thanks

***EDIT***

Have added example table data and structure as well as what should be added

```
tblData

Event Title | Event Date | Last Name | First Name  | Email               | Age |
__________________________________________________________________________________

            | 02/02/2013 | Collins   | James       | collins@hotmail.com | 24  |

POP ACT     | 01/29/2012 | Romas     | Ian         | pizza@gmail.com     |     |
```

So from above we can see that the first record is missing an Event Title and the second is missing an Age. So what should be output to tblExceptions would be:

```
tblExceptions

 Event Title | Event Date | Last Name | First Name  | Email               | Age
__________________________________________________________________________________

             | 02/02/2013 | Collins   | James       | collins@hotmail.com | 24

 POP ACT     | 01/29/2012 | Romas     | Ian         | pizza@gmail.com     |
```

The more I think about this the more complicated it seems as the field Age is blank for the first record but not for the next so it would have to be in the table

Hope this clarifies abit

Comment: The table structure is a little confusing.  Can you add an example of what a source record in `tblData` might look like, and what should get added to `tblExceptions`?

Comment: you cann use iif statement. http://www.dbforums.com/microsoft-access/1207761-can-i-use-case-ms-access-query.html

Comment: So basically any record that is missing anything should be copied entirely into `tblExceptions`?  What is the purpose of that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a query to show all `tblData` rows where any of those fields is Null.

```sql
SELECT
    d.[Event Title],
    d.[Event Date],
    d.[Last Name],
    d.[First Name],
    d.Email,
    d.Age
FROM tblData AS d
WHERE
       d.[Event Title] Is Null
    OR d.[Event Date] Is Null
    OR d.[Last Name] Is Null
    OR d.[First Name] Is Null
    OR d.Email Is Null
    OR d.Age Is Null;
```

Ideally, you can then avoid storing copies of those rows in another table (`tblExceptions`).

But if you have a compelling reason to store copies of those rows, you can convert that to an `INSERT` statement ("append query").